# XML editor for writing .ruleML files

Tags: xml, open-source, rule

If there is already a discussion about this somewhere, I'll take a link as an acceptable answer, but I couldn't find one.

Basically, I'm working with a rule-engine that reads rule files in .ruleML. My question is, if anyone has experience working with writing these files using an xml editor, which ones did they find had the most affinity for the task? I might add that I'm looking for an open source software answer.

Edit: Actually, even if you don't have experience with .ruleML, any opinions about open source xml editors might be enough for me to infer what would be most helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [S2REd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/s2red/), the "Syntactic-Semantic RuleML Editor". Editing XML is never pretty, but this tool tries to help, anyway.